# Jekyll layout front matter not working

Tags: yaml, jekyll

I have two projects which I have setup like this:

_config.yml

```
defaults:
  -
    scope:
      path: "" # an empty string here means all files in the project
    values:
      layout: "default"
```

_layouts/default.html

```
---
abc: def
---
<hmtl>
...
```

index.md

```
Hello {{ layout.abc }}
```

when I start jekyll and option the first project I get a html page like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
    Hello def
    </body>
</html>
```

When I load up the second project however, I just get:

```
<html>
    <body>
    Hello 
    </body>
</html>
```

I've been looking at this for hours and cannot figure it out. Everything looks fine and I created the second project by cut and pasting from the first. Yet it doesn't appear to be able to see any of the front matter from the layout.

Anyone have any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: Can you be more specific than saying it's not working? What exactly happens instead? Can you provide a [mcve] of the files you're talking about?

Comment: Repositories urls can be helpful.

Comment: Thanks guys. Re-edited to try and make it clearer. :-)